# Numpy and array shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array that I would like shaped as (19381, 100, 6). Once I convert the array to a numpy array, the shape that I get is (19381,)

```
Input: d.shape
Output: (19381,)
Input: d[0].shape
Output: (100,6)
Input: d[0][0].shape
Output: (6,)
Input: if any(i.shape != (100,6) for i in d):
           print(True)
       else:
           print(False)
Output: False
```

What am I missing? I have tried using

```
d.shape = (19381,100,6)
```

But I get a "cannot reshape array of size 19381 into shape (19381, 100,6)

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring because of the way that I was creating the numpy arrays. I was attempting to do something like

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
l = zip(l1, l2)
np.random.shuffle(l)
l1, l2 = np.array(zip(*l))
```

Once I changed the code to

```
l1, l2 = zip(*l)
l1 = np.array(l1)
l2 = np.array(l2)
```

The shape output was as expected.

Comment: If you're on Python 3, `zip` doesn't return a list any more.